# Сломалась отдача сайтов по http после обновления

Tags: nginx, apache2

Ubuntu 14.04, apache2 + nginx.

Nginx отдает статику для сайта (PHP), phpmyadmin и полностью обслуживает redmine (ROR через passenger), всё остальное уходит на apache сидящий на 8080 порту на локалхосте.

phpmyadmin и redmine доступны только по http, основной сайт на http и https.

Обновился обычным apt-get update && apt-get upgrade. (Не было печали, апдейтов накачали).

После обновления весь трафик, идущий через http, уходит куда-то в никуда (по логам ничего не видно, как будто никто и не заходит), вместо открытия страницы сайта отдается непонятный файл весом в ~57 байт, не открывается ничем, получает название исходя из url. т.е. example.com/somefile.abr скачается как somefile.abr

Подскажите, куда хоть копать. По запросу в духе "site downloads instead of open" вижу только кучу вопросов от людей, не осиливших настроить handler'ы для php и прочих скриптов.

**UPD**
Ответ найден, спасибо @AlexeyTen и вот [этому посту](https://serverfault.com/questions/779594/nginx-http-not-working-downloads-a-file-called-download). К ответам в том вопросе хочу добавить что

```
listen 80 http2;
```

даже в конфиге одного из сайтов меняет поведение каждого из них, что странно.

Comment: По каким логам ничего не видно? nginx'а или Apache? Статика отдаётся?

Comment: С какими заголовками файл отдается?

Comment: И там и там. Статика на основном сайте по https отдается, в том же phpmyadmin'е не отдается (пытался открыть прямые ссылки на лого или другие картинки, результат тот же).
Могу дать ссылки на сайты или конфиги, если поможет, но они в целом типовые.

Как посмотреть с какими заголовками отдается файл?

Comment: начните с выяснения, идут ли запросы именно к вашему компьютеру, и процесс ли nginx на них отвечает.

Comment: *Как посмотреть с какими заголовками отдается файл?* — например: `$ wget -S --spider url`

Comment: @TexElless: проверьте через `netstat -anpt` что ваши веб-сервера слушают нужные порты. Проверьте содержимое директив `access_log` и `error_log` в nginx'е. Убедитесь, что файлы, которые в них указаны, существуют. Проверьте их права. Так же уточните - вы лишь журналы доступа смотрели? В журнал ошибок заглядывали? Что там?

Comment: Файл отдается с 200 статусом и без хедеров. По нетстату всё ок, nginx висит на 80 и 443. 
Логи смотрел и access и error, как общие, так и по конкретным vhost'ам, и у apache и у nginx. Смотрел просто сами директории через ls -l, время изменения меняется только у access лога у основного сайта, который работает. В нём ничего лишнего или подозрительного нет, т.е. соединения, качающие этот самый файл нигде не фиксируются.
В общем-то права и конфиги не менялись "до" и "после" обновления.
Посмотреть какой файл можно например [тут](http://redmine.fe-it.com)

Comment: @TexElless: при обновлении - какое конкретно ПО обновлялось, имеющее отношение к работе сайтов? nginx, Apache, PHP, что-нибудь ещё? Если, к примеру, Apache обновился с 2.2 до 2.4, то там было большое кол-во изменений, требующих правки конфигурационных файлов - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

Comment: @МАН69К Апдейты только минорных версий. Рестарты nginx или apache даже никаких warning'ов не выдают. Обновились php, mysql, apache и nginx. В общем весь стек. Но при этом весь стек продолжает исправно работать на https версии основного сайта. [тыц](https://www.fe-it.com)

Comment: @TexElless: запросы к www.fe-it.com и fe-it.com обрабатываются в nginx в одном server_name?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/779594/nginx-http-not-working-downloads-a-file-called-download

Comment: @МАН69К да, в одном блоке server {}, просто с двумя listen.

Comment: @AlexeyTen ии это помогло. Я находил этот пост, но решил всё не совсем правильно. Я пробовал убрать http2 из конфигов пхпмайадмина и редмайна, но забыл убрать из конфига основного сайта, не трогая его, потому что он работал. 
Это правда странно. listen 80 http2; в конфиге одного vhost'а с server_name fe-it.com www.fe-it.com ломал поведение двух других vhost'ов с другими именами. Как это работает? Почему вообще конфиг одного сайта влиял на поведение других?

Comment: Потому что `listen` это такая особая директива. Например когда вы пишете `listen 80;` в десятке серверных блоков, nginx на самом деле конечно открывает сокет только один раз. И многие опции у listen можно задавать только в одном блоке, но при этом они влияют на все блоки с заданной парой адрес:порт.

Comment: @AlexeyTen вот оно как. Спасибо, теперь понятно, хоть и всё еще выглядит не очень очевидно.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась во флаге `http2` директивы `listen` в соседнем блоке `server`.

Несколько неочевидно, но несмотря на то что `listen` объявляется внутри блока `server` его флаги могут влиять на другие блоки `server` которые слушают тот же порт.

Например:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name server1;
}

server {
    listen 80 http2;
    server_name server2;
}
```

тут `server1` тоже будет пытаться принимать запросы по протоколу `http2`. Особенно сложно обнаружить такую ошибку когда блоки разнесены по разным файлам.